# Create pink noise image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, fft, noise

I'd like to generate a 2D image of arbitrary size containing randomly generated pink noise.  [Wikipedia suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_noise) that the 2D generalization of pink noise will have energy that falls off as 1/f^2.  I found [some code on the MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42919-pink-red-blue-and-violet-noise-generation-with-matlab-implementation/content/pinknoise.m) that computes a 1D pink noise vector.  But I don't know how to properly generalize it to two dimensions -- I'm not very familiar with the fft, and my naive attempt below produces complex vectors when I compute the ifft.

```
function pink = pinkNoiseImage(nrow,ncol)

rnrow = 2.^(ceil(log2(nrow)));
rncol = 2.^(ceil(log2(ncol)));
r = randn(rnrow,rncol);
rf = fft(r);
rnup = rnrow/2+1;
cnup = rncol/2+1;
frf = kron(1./sqrt(1:cnup),1./sqrt(1:rnup)');

rf(1:rnup,1:cnup) = rf(1:rnup,1:cnup).*frf;
rf(rnup+1:rnrow,1:cnup) = real(frf(rnrow/2:-1:2,1:cnup))-1i*imag(frf(rnrow/2:-1:2,1:cnup));
rf(1:rnup,cnup+1:rncol) = real(frf(1:rnup,rncol/2:-1:2))-1i*imag(frf(1:rnup,rncol/2:-1:2));
rf(rnup+1:rnrow,cnup+1:rncol) = real(frf(rnrow/2:-1:2,rncol/2:-1:2))-1i*imag(frf(rnrow/2:-1:2,rncol/2:-1:2));

pink = ifft(rf);
```

How can I generate a 2D matrix containing pink noise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't always believe what Wikipedia tells you. Or, read carefully, because the definition of Pink noise is not one to one for 2D. 
Second, you can use the following [FEX file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5091-generate-spatial-data) to generate `1/f^beta` spatial noise, with a normal error distribution. Read more in the documentation of that file.

Comment: Thanks for the FEX reference.  It turns out that the Brownian noise computed by that file may be more useful to me than pink noise.