# How do I implement red noise?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I've just read the [red noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_noise) article after a professor mentioned it in a lecture.

My idea was to start with a random number in {0,..., 255}. Then I finish the first row from left to right by adding a random offset in {0, ..., 255}.
As soon as the first line is finished, I will take the average of the upper and the left element and add a random offset for the next pixel.

This way, I create the image from left to right, top to bottom.

I've implemented it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Create a red noise RGB image of the dimensions you want."""

import numpy
import Image
import random


def create_red_noise(outfile, width, height, r=10):
    """
    Create red noise RGB image

    Parameters
    ----------
    outfile : str
    width : int
    height : int
    r : int
        Random maximum offset compared to the last pixel
    """
    array = numpy.random.rand(height, width, 3) * 255
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if y == 0:
                if x == 0:
                    continue
                else:
                    for i in range(3):
                        array[y][x][i] = (array[y][x-1][i] +
                                          random.randint(-r, r))
            else:
                if x == 0:
                    for i in range(3):
                        array[y][x][i] = (array[y-1][x][i] +
                                          random.randint(-r, r))
                else:
                    for i in range(3):
                        array[y][x][i] = (((array[y-1][x][i] +
                                            array[y-1][x-1][i]) / 2.0 +
                                           random.randint(-r, r)))
    im_out = Image.fromarray(array.astype('uint8')).convert('RGBA')
    im_out.save(outfile)


def get_parser():
    """Get parser object for create_random_image.py."""
    from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,
                            formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file",
                        dest="filename",
                        help="write red noise image to FILE",
                        default="red-noise.jpg",
                        metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_argument("-x", "--width",
                        dest="width",
                        default=1280,
                        type=int,
                        help="width of the image")
    parser.add_argument("-y", "--height",
                        dest="height",
                        default=960,
                        type=int,
                        help="height of the image")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--offset",
                        dest="offset",
                        default=10,
                        type=int,
                        help="maximum offset compared to the neighbors")
    return parser


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = get_parser().parse_args()
    create_red_noise(args.filename, args.width, args.height, args.offset)
```

which gives

[image]

It looks cool. However, I think it should look more like this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Red.noise.col.png

What am I doing wrong / how can I fix it?

Comment: On the wikipedia image you can clearly see heavy filtering, it's smooth, there are no rough edges. Colored noizes are typically implemented by attenuating the high frequency components.. at least in the audio domain. I don't see a way to "fix" your code, you should look up the right approach (I'm sure there are plenty of google hits).

Comment: As far as I know, the *colour* of noise says something about the (power) spectrum of the given noise. Your striped image can still have a red noise spectrum. Spatial variation is not related to the noise being red, is it?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: but it won't be a real *noise* (that is, random).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath well, at least not one that's coming from Brownian motion:)

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be when you are calculating the correlated value when you have a valid position to the left and above. You have:

```
array[y][x][i] = (((array[y-1][x][i] +
                    array[y-1][x-1][i]) / 2.0 +
                   random.randint(-r, r)))
```

I think this should be:

```
array[y][x][i] = (((array[y-1][x][i] +
                    array[y][x-1][i]) / 2.0 +
                   random.randint(-r, r)))
```

In your version you are taking the average of the pixel above and diagonlly above and to the left when you actually want the pixel above and the pixel to the left.

Comment: Aside from this bug I think the only difference between your algorithm and the image provided from  the wiki is probably the hue. Hope this helps!

Comment: This explains why the lines aren't 45 degrees diagonal, but it doesn't explain why the general pattern doesn't match the provided screenshot

Comment: Okay so my solution obviously does not create brown noise as pointed out by @o_o . 2D correlated noise is a little more complicated than 1D noise and this is glossed over by the wiki. Here is another SO exchange concerning pink noise generation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367474/create-pink-noise-image-in-matlab you can follow the provided link to a MATLAB implementation to produce either pink or brown/red noise. The solution involves an inverse Fourier transform with random phase shifts.